# I need help to understand how to select words for a If statement from my function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
tequila = input("What do you want to buy? ")

if ---- is tequila:
    
    tequilaprice = 45.67 
    
    print(tequilaprice)
    
else:
    
    print("not tequila! GOODBYE!")
```

I want my code to run if only the word tequila is typed in the string and not another word like car.

Comment: `if tequila == "tequila":`?

Comment: If you need help with this, you need to go back to the tutorials and learn the language basics.

Comment: I'm a beginner!

Comment: You're still expected to learn the basics.

Comment: okay! well I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do it is just by creating an if statement.

```
user_input = input("What do you wanna buy? ")

if user_input == "tequila":
    tequilaprice = 45.67
    print(tequilaprice)
else:
    print("not tequila! GOODBYE!")
```

something like this should do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only `tequila` to be a valid answer it is as simple as you can think:

```py
input_str = input("What do you want to buy? ")

if "tequila" == input_str:
    tequilaprice = 45.67
    print(tequilaprice)

else:
    print("not tequila! GOODBYE!")
```

In your example you included `is`. It won't work with it because it compares Python objects rather than values. The literal `tequila` in the code is a different Python object than the value returned by the `input()` function even if their value is the same.

If you're using `input()` you probably also want to ignore all white characters typed by the user like spaces and tabs. You can do that with `strip()`:

```py
if "tequila" == input_str.strip():
```

If you want to run the code if `tequila` is a part of the input string then you can use `in`:

```py
input_str = input("What do you want to buy? ")

if "tequila" in input_str:
    tequilaprice = 45.67
    print(tequilaprice)

else:
    print("not tequila! GOODBYE!")
```

E.g. `I want tequila` as an input:

```py
>>> What do you want to buy? I want tequila
>>> 45.67
```

You can also use `input_str.lower()` to ignore any letter capitalization. In that case `tequila`, `Tequila` and `tEqUiLa` all will be valid answers.